# Modal dialog becomes non-modal

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog, sdi

I have MFC SDI application, in it modal dialog is displayed. During that second dialog can be displayed, which is also modal. Second dialog is doing some job and auto-closed by

```
dlg->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
```

All that works but after second dialog is closed first dialog is not modal any more, this means I can click the main window of the application.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: Specify the first dialog as parent for the second.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf 
 
I just tried your advise and I think it helped. Post it as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A window can only handle one modal dialog at a time.

Therefore, specify the first dialog as parent for the second.